# Create a Maya UI window in cpp

Tags: c++, user-interface, plugins, window, maya

I am working on a C++ Maya plugin, and would like this plugin to open a UI window in Maya in which I can add my own elements (2d). How can I open a window in C++ for Maya ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API exists mainly to get you closer to Maya's core. It is mainly used to interface with it's "brain"/core functionality.

UI, on the other hand, is best left to MEL and/or Python to deal with.

This also promotes a bit of MVC practice.

This link will answer your questions of how exactly to call MEL from C++ on Maya, and some suggestions on dealing with UI in your plugins: http://ewertb.soundlinker.com/api/api.019.php

Another interesting, bit possibly a more involved and powerful route to go is to use Qt with your plugin. Qt is C++ and can be used with your C++ plugin if needed. Check this thread out for some direction: http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-997360.html quoting the thread: make sure you check out the examples in the Maya dev-kit folder.

**Update:**
If you want to start out learning Qt/PyQt/PySide for Maya, I suggest looking into these: http://zurbrigg.com/maya-python/category/pyqt-projects-for-maya

I hope that helps.

Comment: MEL allows me indeed to open a window (with menus). What cpp equivalent Qt class should I use to open the same kind of window ? I would like to put as much as possible in the cpp rather than in the mel. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the C++ api does not provide classes or methods to extensively work with UI. You will have to go the Mel/python route or the qt route unfortunately.

Comment: Would you know in qt what class would help me to create a Maya window (like Node Editor) + menu ?

Comment: That is a very broad question, Laurent. I can only point you in the right direction if you want to learn PyQt Dev for Maya. I have updated my answer with a tutorial to learn Maya Qt dev.

Comment: Laurent, if you found any part of my answer useful, please vote it up. Thank you.